# R - ggplot2 geom_bar() doesn't plot correctly column's values

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am new to `R`

I would like plot using `ggplot2`'s `geom_bar()`:

```
top_r_cuisine <- r_cuisine %>%
   group_by(Rcuisine) %>%
   summarise(count = n()) %>%
   arrange(desc(count)) %>%
   top_n(10)
```

[image]
But when I try to plot this result by:

```
ggplot(top_r_cuisine, aes(x = Rcuisine)) +
       geom_bar()
```

I get this:
[image]
which doesn't represent the values in `top_r_cuisine`. Why?

**EDIT:**
I have tried:

[image]

Comment: you need to tell it what `y` is: `ggplot(top_r_cuisine, aes(x = Rcuisine, y = count)) +
       geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Comment: also, a screenshot of data isn't useful, it would be better to use `dput(top_r_cuisine)` and paste the output of that into your question.

Comment: @SymbolixAU I have tried with  `aes(x = Rcuisine, y = count)` but I get the same result.

Comment: try `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar` or like @SymbolixAU suggested `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c_count=c(23,45,67,43,54)
country=c("america","india","germany","france","italy")
# sample Data frame #
finaldata = data.frame(country,c_count)
ggplot(finaldata, aes(x=country)) +
geom_bar(aes(weight = c_count))
```

you need to assign the weights in the geom_bar() [image]